# Equality check with fractions in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, precision, floating-accuracy, fractions

So I'm learning that Lisp does fractions which is great. But why then does this equality check return NIL:

```
* (= 0.2 1/5)          

NIL
```

...while it returns True if it's converted to `float` first:

```
* (= 0.2 (float 1/5))

T
```

I've tried in `SBCL` and `CLISP`.

Is the implementation incomplete or is there a special reason or logic behind this behaviour?

Comment: Inaccuracy of floating point numbers? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1089026/124319

Comment: also,  `(= 0.5 1/2)` returns `T`. 0.5 is  terminating in both base 2 and 10: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1096929/124319

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Ratios in Common Lisp**

Note that *fractions* (which itself is not a numeric type in Common Lisp) are converted to *rationals* in Lisp. `rational`, `ratio` and `integer` (and others) are actual numeric types in Common Lisp. If you enter a fraction, it is normalized to a rational (an integer or a ratio number).

```
CL-USER 16 > 3/9
1/3

CL-USER 17 > 9/9
1

CL-USER 18 > 6/9
2/3
```

**Numeric comparison**

When float and ratio are compared, the float value is converted to a rational and then exact comparison is done. See: [CLHS, Rule of Float and Rational Contagion](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/12_ada.htm).

**The ratio is not converted to a float, but the float is converted to a rational.**

The problem appears because some floats are not converted to the ratios you would expect. The underlying issue is that floating point numbers have not necessarily an *exact* representation. The conversion of a non-exact number to an exact rational is not necessary giving the naively expected result.

Unfortunately the conversion of `0.2` to a rational number is not necessarily `1/5`, but this:

```
CL-USER 7 > (rational 0.2)
13421773/67108864
```

But `0.5` is `1/2`.

```
CL-USER 8 > (rational 0.5)
1/2
```

This is what happens in your examples:

```
CL-USER 9 > (= 1/2 (rational 0.5))
T

CL-USER 10 > (= 1/5 (rational 0.2))
NIL
```

So it is not

```
CL-USER 14 > (= 0.2 (float 1/5))
T
```

But:

```
CL-USER 15 > (= (rational 0.2) 1/5)
NIL
```

Note that the type `rational` combines the disjoint subtypes `ratio` and `integer`. Thus `(rational 1.0)` could be an integer, and not a ratio.

Answer (score 3):

The [specification](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq_sle.htm#EQ) about `=` says:

> The value of `=` is true if all numbers are the same in value; otherwise it is false.

While the [specification](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_real.htm#real) on `real` says:

> The types `rational` and `float` are disjoint subtypes of type `real`.

In other words, you can compare them because they are both *numbers*, but they are different because, since the subtypes are disjoint, they are *different* values.

What you can do is convert them to the same “subset” of numbers, float, and then the comparison will return true.

The reason for this behaviour is that `float` numbers in general have an approximate representation (see the comment by @coredump and the link), while rational numbers have an exact representation, so it is not very sensible to compare values that could “look” externally identical but are different in the internal (binary) representation.